# Remove facebook fan page profile picture on like box plugin

Tags: facebook, facebook-likebox, user-profile

I just want to ask a simple question about facebook like box http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/ I just want to remove the fan page profile photo.. Is there a solution for this? Thanks!

Comment: Have you found the way to do this? I need it as well

Answer (score 2):

First: It is against the facebook rules to change or hide things in the social plugins.

That being said, afaik it is not possible anymore to use custom css in the social plugins. A long time ago you could pass the absolute URL of a css file to the plugin code but it does not work anymore.

I would recommend using a simple Like button. If you really need the stream of the page too, you could just use an app to read them by yourself, in that case even with your own design.

Answer (score 1):

I just thought to answer this question as someone else might need this information in the future. All you need to do is reduce the width of the facebook like box. That’s it. I have done that in my website www.bringhopes.ca.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following CSS to hide the image

> ```
> img.profileimage
> {
>     display:none;
> }
> ```

Comment: I recommend using an !important but I have had success with this method.